# How do I execute my python code from code2.py with __init__.py and code.py inside

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a directory structure like below:

```
├── data
│   └── abc.txt
└── modules
   ├── code2.py
   ├── code.py
   ├── code.pyc
   └── __init__.py
```

I want to execute code.py by using just the code2.py and `__init__.py` file.Technically my `__init__.py` file is empty.

So far my code2.py file looks like below ( I am sure that there is something I am missing):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from  code import *
```

How do I execute the code.py from code2.py

Comment: What do you mean by "execute"? Do you want to executed a function? Do you have any function calls inside `code.py` that are made in the global namespace?

Comment: I want to run code.py from code2.py. Yes, there are  functions inside code.py in global namespace. My prime objective is to use the functionality of `__init__.py` in running code.py

Comment: try `from modules import code`.

Answer (score 0):

The __ init__.py files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, __ init__.py can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the __ all__ variable, described later.

If you really want to use it though, this is how :

1.Treat it like a module: import file. This is good because it's secure, fast, and maintainable. Code gets reused as it's supposed to be done. Most Python libraries run using multiple methods stretched over lots of files. Highly recommended. Note that if your file is called file.py, your import should not include the .py extension at the end.

2.The infamous (and unsafe) exec command: execfile('file.py'). Insecure, hacky, usually the wrong answer. Avoid where possible.

3.Spawn a shell process: os.system('python file.py'). Use when desperate.

Comment: Say I have another file code2.py inside the same folder co-exisitng with , code.py and `__init__.py`. In that case how will my content of code2.py will look like if all I want to execute code.py.

Comment: Just go with any of the 3 methods I outlined above!